# SQL String match with Like

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to validate a string with a like pattern, which only consists of the following characters and I'm getting close to it but can still bypass my curernt expression:

```
valid characters: numbers 0-9, alphanumeric chars + . = \
```

expression:

```
'%[^[0-9A-Za-z+.\_\-\=\\\]]%' ESCAPE '\'
```

But with that expression, also strings with square brackets and "-"-characters are counted as correct. If I swap the inner brackets to normal brackets like so

```
'%[^(0-9A-Za-z+.\_\-\=\\\)]%' ESCAPE '\'
```

I still have the same issue but this time with normal brackets. 
Test data I'm toying with:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp
CREATE TABLE #temp(
    string varchar(max),
    expectedResult varchar(max),
    result varchar(max)
)
insert #temp(string,expectedResult)
values
('da)ssdas', 'invalid'),
('DFGHJ§$%', 'invalid'),
('+=8rt8\\//12=+', 'invalid'),
('[BIGBEAR]', 'invalid'),
('BIG-BEAR', 'invalid'),
('x[BIGBEAR]x', 'invalid'),
('(BIGBEAR)', 'invalid'),
('+=8rt8Ahd12=+', 'valid')

update #temp
set result =    CASE WHEN string like '%[^[0-9A-Za-z+.\_\-\=\\\]]%' ESCAPE '\' 
                        THEN 'invalid'
                ELSE'valid'
                END

select * from #temp
```

result

```
string         expectedResult   result
da)ssdas       invalid          invalid
DFGHJ§$%        invalid          invalid
+=8rt8\\//12=+ invalid          invalid
[BIGBEAR]      invalid          valid
BIG-BEAR       invalid          valid
x[BIGBEAR]x    invalid          valid
(BIGBEAR)      invalid          invalid
+=8rt8Ahd12=+  valid            valid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want:

```
'%[^0-9A-Za-z+.\_\-\=\\]%' ESCAPE '\'
```

The `^` in the character class applies to all characters.  I would use a different escape character for readability.  The hyphen as the first character in the character class means a hyphen, so the only character you need to escape is the backslash:

```
'%[^-0-9A-Za-z+=$\]%' ESCAPE '$'
```